# Add the folder's name to all `.bin` files in that folder

Tags: batch-rename

I have spent almost one day and a half searching for this but couldn't find an answer.

I am looking to add the folder's name as a prefix to all files ending with `.bin` in that folder.

So, if the folder's name is `ABC` and it contains the files `aa.bin`, `bb.bin`, `cc.bin`, etc. then I need them to be renamed as `ABC-aa.bin`, `ABC-bb.bin`, `ABC-cc.bin`, etc.

Also, this folder `ABC` has subfolders, let's call them: `ABC1`, `ABC2`, `ABC3`, etc. which also have `.bin` files. For example `ABC1` has `aa1.bin`, `bb1.bin`, `cc1.bin`, etc.

I need that command to go through all folders and append that sub-folder's name to files inside it too. So, `aa1.bin` will be `ABC1-aa1.bin`, and so on.

**Directory structure:**

```
.
└── ABC
    ├── aa.bin
    ├── ABC1
    │   ├── aa1.bin
    │   └── bb1.bin
    ├── ABC2
    │   ├── aa2.bin
    │   └── bb2.bin
    ├── bb.bin
    └── cc.bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a "one-liner" to do, using shell built-ins to manipulate the filenames:

```
find . -name '*.bin' -exec sh -c 'p="${1%/*}"; f="${1##*/}"; echo mv -- "$1" "$p/${p##*/}-$f"' sh {} \;
```

Test it in the target directory and remove the `echo` if the results look correct

e.g. given

```
$ tree .
.
└── ABC
    ├── aa.bin
    ├── ABC1
    │   ├── aa1.bin
    │   └── bb1.bin
    ├── ABC2
    │   ├── aa2.bin
    │   └── bb2.bin
    ├── bb.bin
    └── cc.bin

3 directories, 7 files
```

then

```
$ find . -name '*.bin' -exec sh -c 'p="${1%/*}"; f="${1##*/}"; echo mv -- "$1" "$p/${p##*/}-$f"' sh {} \;
mv -- ./ABC/ABC2/bb2.bin ./ABC/ABC2/ABC2-bb2.bin
mv -- ./ABC/ABC2/aa2.bin ./ABC/ABC2/ABC2-aa2.bin
mv -- ./ABC/aa.bin ./ABC/ABC-aa.bin
mv -- ./ABC/bb.bin ./ABC/ABC-bb.bin
mv -- ./ABC/ABC1/bb1.bin ./ABC/ABC1/ABC1-bb1.bin
mv -- ./ABC/ABC1/aa1.bin ./ABC/ABC1/ABC1-aa1.bin
mv -- ./ABC/cc.bin ./ABC/ABC-cc.bin
```

looks good, so remove the `echo` and run it again

```
$ find . -name '*.bin' -exec sh -c 'p="${1%/*}"; f="${1##*/}"; mv -- "$1" "$p/${p##*/}-$f"' sh {} \;
```

giving

```
$ tree .
.
└── ABC
    ├── ABC1
    │   ├── ABC1-aa1.bin
    │   └── ABC1-bb1.bin
    ├── ABC2
    │   ├── ABC2-aa2.bin
    │   └── ABC2-bb2.bin
    ├── ABC-aa.bin
    ├── ABC-bb.bin
    └── ABC-cc.bin

3 directories, 7 files
```

Comment: Technically `find` is `/usr/bin/find` :)

Comment: Somehow this isn't working.. filename doesn't changes.

This is what I get:

mv -- ./p6modem.bin ./.-p6modem.bin
mv -- ./p7/p7modem.bin ./p7/p7-p7modem.bin

See, no changes to filename are being made. Using the command as it is BTW.

Comment: @Krishna did you remove the `echo` command? @Kos sorry by "it" I meant the slicing-'n'-dicing of the filenames - not the `find` part

Comment: Works 100% right out of the box!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `find`, `basename`, `dirname` and `mv` commands. For example like in this simple script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(find ABC -name '*.bin'); 
do 
  filename="$(basename $f)" 
  dir="$(dirname $f)"
  lastdir="$(basename $dir)"
  newname="$lastdir-$filename"
  newpath="$dir/$newname"
  mv $f $newpath
done
```

Here I'm using find to recursively find all `.bin` files in ABC, then iterate over them and extracting the last folder name. Then the new path is constructed and the file is moved to the same directory but with the new name.

**Edit**:
In order to execute this script copy its contents to some file. Let's say the filename is `renameFiles.sh`. Then make it executable:

```
chmod +x renameFiles.sh
```

After this you can execute it with `./renameFiles.sh`. Notice that the folder where you put this file should be the same where your ABC folder is located.

```
renameFiles.sh
ABC
  aa.bin
  bb.bin
  ABC1
    aa1.bin
    etc.
```

Comment: I am totally new to Linux. Don't know how to use 'for' thing .. sorry if you feel upset about this...
When I enter !/bin/bash in terminal, I only get error... (event not found).. looking to fix it, BTW.

Comment: I updated the answer so hopefully its clear now.

Comment: I researched on it and had found out. Exactly how you are guiding.
Did that and it's working alright now. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `rename`:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
rename -n '(! -f $_ || ! /.bin$/) && next; $" = "/"; my @f = split("/"); $f[@f-1] =~ s/^/$f[@f-2]-/; $_ = "@f"' **
```

- `shopt -s globstar`: If set, the pattern '**' used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a '/', only directories and subdirectories match.
- `rename -n '! -f $_ && next; $" = "/"; my @f = split("/"); $f[@f-1] =~ s/^/$f[@f-2]-/; $_ = "@f"' **`: performs a dry-run of the following. For each filename resulting from the `**` globbing: if the file is not a regular file or the filename doesn't end with `.bin`, skips to the next filename; sets the output field separator to `/`; splits the filename on `/`; prepends the second to last field followed by `-` to the last field; assigns the new filename to the default variable (`$_`).

If the result is the expected one, remove the `-n` option from the `rename` command.

```bsh
$ tree
.
└── ABC
    ├── aa.bin
    ├── ABC1
    │   ├── aa1.bin
    │   └── bb1.bin
    ├── ABC2
    │   ├── aa2.bin
    │   └── bb2.bin
    ├── bb.bin
    └── cc.bin

3 directories, 7 files
$ rename -n '(! -f $_ || ! /.bin$/) && next; $" = "/"; my @f = split("/"); $f[@f-1] =~ s/^/$f[@f-2]-/; $_ = "@f"' **
Exiting subroutine via next at (eval 4) line 1.
rename(ABC/aa.bin, ABC/ABC-aa.bin)
Exiting subroutine via next at (eval 4) line 1.
rename(ABC/ABC1/aa1.bin, ABC/ABC1/ABC1-aa1.bin)
rename(ABC/ABC1/bb1.bin, ABC/ABC1/ABC1-bb1.bin)
Exiting subroutine via next at (eval 4) line 1.
rename(ABC/ABC2/aa2.bin, ABC/ABC2/ABC2-aa2.bin)
rename(ABC/ABC2/bb2.bin, ABC/ABC2/ABC2-bb2.bin)
rename(ABC/bb.bin, ABC/ABC-bb.bin)
rename(ABC/cc.bin, ABC/ABC-cc.bin)
```

Comment: It's a wonderful command.. but how to restrict it to .bin files only? Thanks!
That it (already) excludes directories and sub-directories too is good.

Comment: @user3647217 Fair enough, didn't think that would have renamed even files not ending with `.bin`, edited the answer. Try this instead: `rename -n '(! -f $_ || ! /.bin$/) && next; $" = "/"; my @f = split("/"); $f[@f-1] =~ s/^/$f[@f-2]-/; $_ = "@f"' **`.